# Как вывести в цикле for базу sql

Tags: python

Например я подключаюсь к базе

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("base.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT url, age FROM logins")
for line in cursor.fetchall():
    print(line)
```

Но он выводит всё в одну строку
Можно мне как то вывести что бы шел цикл for что то вроде

```
url age
url age
url age
```

Мне нужно проверять в каждой строке на слово
Например выводить только все строки в которых есть url

Comment: Вариантов несколько. Можно SQL запрос на вывод данных организовать через список, например. А список распечатать в порядке индексирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть того что вам надо.
Создал тестовую бд. Данные в нее занес руками в `sqllitestudio`: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('parser.sqlite', check_same_thread = False)
cursor = conn.cursor()
with conn:
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logins` (`url` STRING ,`age` STRING)")
    conn.commit()

cursor.execute("SELECT url, age FROM logins")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    if row[0]: #проверка что строка в столбце url не пустая
        print("{0} {1}".format(row[0], row[1])) 

cursor.close()
```

результат в консоли:

```
url1 age1
url2 age2
```